# How to reset screen time app limit in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I have screen time limit set up for Social apps with a passcode. After allowing an app to be used for the rest of the day, if I change my mind afterwards how can I lock that app again besides waiting until the next day?

I have tried disable screen time and enable it again. Also tried to change the passcode. Nothing works, the app stays unlocked no matter what I tried.

Comment: If you re-enable the limit and set it for one minute, does it let you tally up more usage and then lock a second time?

Comment: No unfortunately it seems to not do that. Playing around with the limit was one of the things I tried too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you **can't** do that because you have approved the application for that day... So you can't switch the app restriction back for this day, you must wait for tomorrow.

But instead of "allow app for the **rest** of the day" when the time limit has been reached, you can simply cancel the time limit for this app in the settings...

If you still want to have the screen time limit again afterwards, you simply have to reactivate the app limit in the settings and then the app can't be called again, when the preset screen time is reached (even if it is switched off and on again, it remembers the time used).

However, that is not the point of the thing (screen-time-limit-app), but fulfills your purpose!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It didn't occur to me to do this at all!